# Ubuntu system monitor columns explain?

Tags: system, system-monitor

[image]

Can anybody explain Ubuntu system monitor columns?
Disk read, disk write, disk read total, disk write total?

Comment: `Disk read` and `Disk write` is the amount of data currently read from or written to the disk in bytes (or kilobytes) per second by that process. `Disk read total` and `Disk write total` is the amount of data read/written by that process in total. What exactly is unclear to you?

Comment: you have explained what unclear was! thanks :)

Comment: @PerlDuck `Disk Write Total`, just to confirm, is the data written to the disk by a process from a time since it was launched, right? Restarting the computer will reset this metric for that process, right? Just trying to confirm because I just saw `58.6GB` in disk write total column by, wait for it, freaking variety .. the wallpaper manager. And my PC hasn't up for even a couple of days, and my download interval is "every 2 hours". MAN!!!

Comment: @Ejaz Exactly. It's not neccessary to restart the computer to reset the counters. If a certain process exits, the corresponding line in the system monitor disappears. If the process is started again, the counter starts at 0.